# For all positive real numbers, is $f(x)=\sqrt{x}+x+2$ one to one?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I understand that in order to prove this to be one to one, I need to prove $2$ numbers, $a$ and $b$, in the same set are equal.

This is what I did:

$$\sqrt{a} + a + 2 = \sqrt{b} + b + 2$$
$$\sqrt{a} + a = \sqrt{b} + b$$
$$a + a^2 = b + b^2$$

How would I arrive at $a = b$? Is it possible?

Comment: It is not true that $(x+y)^2=x^2+y^2$.

Comment: It is not correct to go from the second to the third line.

Comment: Oh, alright. Where would I go from step 2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$f(x)=\sqrt{x}+x+2$ is strictly increasing on $(0,\infty)$, so it's one-one (suppose not, use the strict monotonicity to draw a contradiction).

Or, from your second step,

$$\sqrt{a} + a = \sqrt{b} + b\iff \sqrt{a} - \sqrt{b}+ a -b=0 \iff(\sqrt{a} - \sqrt{b})(1+\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b})=0 $$

Since $1+\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b}>0$, we have $\sqrt{a} - \sqrt{b}=0$.

Answer (score 1):

You were basically done:
$$
\sqrt{a}+a=\sqrt{b}+b\implies 0=(\sqrt{a}-\sqrt{b})(\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b}+1)\implies \sqrt{a}=\sqrt{b}\implies a=b.
$$